# Commutation of small limits, category theory, isomorphism,limits commute with limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

Let $D$ and $D′$ be small catgeories and let $C$ be a category which admits limits of shape $D$ as well as limits of shape $D′$. Then these limits commute with each other, in that

for $F:D^{op} \times D^{' op} →C$ a functor , with corresponding induced functors

$F_D:D^{ ′\ op}→[D^{op},C]$ and $F_{D' } : {D}^{op} \to [D^{'\ op},C]$ then

$\lim F≃\lim_D(\lim_{D′} F_D)≃\lim_{D ′}(\lim_D F_{D′})$.

How do I prove the last two isomorphisms?

Comment: What definition of limit are you using?

Comment: Prove that $\lim_D(\lim_{D'}F_D)$ satisfies the universal property to be (isomorphic to) the limit of $F$.

Comment: Why are you taking $D'^{op}$? That would get you colimits, not limits.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Please see [here](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/universal+constructions+--+adjunction,+limit+and+Kan+extension): small limits commute with small limits

Comment: @user122424 Note that your link also uses $D^{op}$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, I believe that the link is correct. You disagree? I just copied the whole paragraph from there.

Comment: @user122424 Your link is correct for this part, but I wanted to point out that it considers a functor $D^{op}\times D'^{op}\to C$. You only have $D\times D'^{op}$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, thank you. Fixed.Do you please have a detailed solution to my OQ?